# Prove that $\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a} = 2\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Why would the following identity hold for any two complex vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{C}^N$
$$\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a} = 2\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a})$$

This is taken from Steven M. Kay's *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing - Detection Theory* page 475.

Does this identity have a name? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, there was a factor 2 missing. May bad. Thank you.

Comment: By the definition of real part, $$\text{Re}(\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{a})=\frac12(\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{a}+\overline{\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{a}}).$$ With that in mind, all that's left is to convince oneself that $\overline{\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{a}}=\mathbf{a}^H \mathbf{b}$.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. (For the sake of completeness: one can show $\overline{\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{a}}=\mathbf{a}^H \mathbf{b}$ using the commutative property of the dot product.)

Comment: What is H? Transpose?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Hermitian conjugate.

Comment: Given that you've solved your own problem, I suggest posting it as an answer so you can accept it and we can provide feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any complex number $z=z_r+iz_i$ and its complex conjugate $\overline{z}=z_r-iz_i$ one can see that
$$z+\overline{z}=z_r+iz_i+z_r-iz_i=2z_r=2\operatorname{Re}(z)$$

The scalar product for any two complex vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{C}^N$ is
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a}^{\operatorname{H}}\mathbf{b} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \overline{a}_kb_k$$ where $\mathbf{a}^{\operatorname{H}}=\overline{\mathbf{a}^{\operatorname{T}}}$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

---

Thus, one has
$$\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a} \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \overline{a}_kb_k +\sum_{k=1}^{N} \overline{b}_ka_k \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\overline{a}_kb_k + \overline{b}_ka_k \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\overline{\overline{b}_ka_k} + \overline{b}_ka_k \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{N}2\operatorname{Re}(\overline{b}_ka_k) \\
=2\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\overline{b}_ka_k\right) \\
=2\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{a})
$$

---

Thank you @Semiclassical for the comment that provided the answer.

References:
[complex dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Generalizations),
[complex identities](https://schools.aglasem.com/45642)